# How can I change the colour/icon of an app on the Unity Panel?

Tags: unity, launcher, icons, steam

There may very well be an answer to this question, but I'm asking it because I only see answers for changing the icon in the "unity launcher" instead of the panel. Here's what I want to accomplish: Steam is all the way on the left. Hard to see, right?

[image]

That's what I want to change. Is there any possible way to change the darkness, or at least the icon, of an application on the unity panel? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like what you're using there is Radiance theme.  Technically, what you want to achieve is doable with Unity Tweak Tool by changing Transparency Level under Panel menu.

In the screenshot below you can see that my Transparency is set to minimum, so it will look dark. You can also see that it raises another problem - font is not readable

[image]

I would recommend you change the icon theme instead of tweaking the panel opacity. A lot of themes pack icons for commonly used softweare such as steam, and you can use one icons from one theme while using completely different theme for window decorations. Here's for example Numix Circle theme for icons, but still keeping Radiance as overall desktop theme

[image]

Again , all this can be edited via Unity Tweak Tool or CompizConfig Settings Manager ( under Unity Plugin ).

Comment: Now I'm having more trouble. I'm attempting to install different themes to fix my problem, I already made the `~/.themes` folder and placed the appropriate folders within it, but they don't show up in Unity Tweak Tool.

Comment: Usually if you install themes, they go into `/usr/share/themes`. I don't recall ever hearing that themes could go into `~/.themes` directory, so it's probably expected behavior that UTT doesn't find them - it probably only looks into `/usr/share` folder